# Redmine installation issues rake command issue, MySQL database issue?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake, redmine

I have somewhat of a complex issue involving several different programs including redmine, MySQL, Ruby, Ruby on Rails etc. This is on Windows XP.

I am following the redmine instructions here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

I am on step 5. where I am suppose to type `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate`

When I type this in the command prompt and hit enter I get an error: "RAILS_ENV" is not a command blah blah.

So I reorder it to: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

**This seems to work correct, but I get the following:**

```
C:\redmine-1.2.1>rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace
* Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
* Invoke environment (first_time)
* Execute environment
  rake aborted!
  Access denied for user 'redmine'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  C:/redmine-1.2.1/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
  /mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `real_connect'
  C:/redmine-1.2.1/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
  /mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `connect'
  C:/redmine-1.2.1/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
  /mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
  C:/redmine-1.2.1/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters
  /mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `new'
```

Here is my `database.yml` file contents:

MySQL (default setup).

```
production:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine
  host: localhost
  username: redmine
  password: ****
  encoding: utf8

development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8

 # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
 # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
 # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

 test:
  adapter: mysql
  database: redmine_test
  host: localhost
  username: root
  password:
  encoding: utf8

test_pgsql:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: redmine_test
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: "postgres"

test_sqlite3:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
```

I really need some direction here. It's almost like there is a problem with my users/passwords. I have changed the passwords not to contain "!" or any other special characters. I do have capital and lower case letters.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DemiSheep

Comment: `Access denied for user 'redmine'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. It seems that you have wrong password for `production` environment. If you're trying to start it in `prod` mode on the same PC as in `dev` mode try to leave it blank otherwise double check username/password spelling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have created the 'redmine' mysql user with the password specified in database.yml?

Can you connect to this user using mysql client? (e.g. `mysql -uredmine -pyourmysqlpassword`)

Does the user have all required privileges?

Comment: Solved the problem, it was a password issue. Now I have a new error: Mysql::Error: query: not connected: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version`
varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? It's possible that the MySQL client doesn't work with Rails 2.3.11. Try downloading this client DLL and put it in your ruby/bin directory: http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll